# How to adjust the order of author names in Latex references (Journal of Finance style)

Tags: reference, latex

I try to replicate the Journal of Finance reference style. In order to do that, the names in the references should be ordered and written with full names as:

- For two authors: LastName1, FirstName1 and FirstName2 LastName2
- For three or more authors: LastName1, FirstName1, FirstName2 LastName2, and FirstName3 LastName3

This is the example reference:

```
@article{examplesource,
  title={Title of article},
  author={LastName1, FirstName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3},
  journal={Journal of Finance},
  volume={40},
  number={1},
  pages={3--73},
  year={2005}}
```

This is what I have defined so far (based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379901/biblatex-how-to-match-the-journal-of-finance-bibliographic-style)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{innamebeforetitle=true} \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}



\begin{document}
\textcite{examplesource} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{examplesource}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated question in one post. The Q&A system works best if each post is about ONE problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you get the full given names with `giveninits=false`
- the sorting you are looking is actually the default behaviour, so you just need to NOT overwrite it with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false,giveninits=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
%\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{innamebeforetitle=true} \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}



\begin{document}
\textcite{baez/article} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{aksin}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]